# On a stack's package file, what is the difference between library and executables dependencies?

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack

In **Haskell**, while using **stack**, there are three places where we can define **dependencies** on the `package.yaml` file; under `library` and `executables`. What is the difference between defining a dependency in these places and when should I use them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's say you want to build and application with two front ends: CLI and a GUI, both using the same underliying logic. Obviously, your CLI doesn't use any graphical libraries, so It shouldn't depend on them and viceversa. Your `package.yaml` will look something like.

```
name:                my-app
version:             0.1.0.0

# This are the dependencies all the components depends on. 
dependencies:
- base >= 4.7 && < 5

# This is the description of your "common logic" i.e. the library 
library:
  source-dirs: src
# depends on whatever libraries of your choice
  dependencies:
    - bytestring
    - megaparsec
    - parser-combinators
    - transformers

executables:
# The executable name for the cli
  my-app-cli:
# The main function is in cli.hs
    main:                cli.hs
    source-dirs:         app
    ghc-options:
      - -Wall
      - -Wextra
      - -threaded
      - -rtsopts
      - -with-rtsopts=-qg
# It depends on you library, the base library (which remember is at the top of the file), and on whatever other libraries you use to build the cli, for example optparse-applicative
    dependencies:
      - my-app
      - optparse-applicative


# The executable name for the GUI
  my-app-gui:
# The main function is on gui.hs
    main:                gui.hs
    source-dirs:         app
    ghc-options:
      - -Wall
      - -Wextra
      - -threaded
      - -rtsopts
      - -with-rtsopts=-qg
# Again, It depends on your library, the base, and a GUI library of your choice. Example monomer.
    dependencies:
      - my-app
      - monomer
```

Now when you run `stack build` it will create two executables, one named `my-app-cli` and other `my-app-gui`, each with its own dependencies, but sharing the common ones. Ideally one could run `stack build my-app:my-app-cli` to build just one of the executables, but for some reason `stack` builds everything (which apparently is due to some `cabal` behaviour... don't know, don't care)

That been said, I don't think this is different from other programming languages. For example, I tend to structure my `Python` code the same way. A common library with its own `requirements.txt` and then different applications each with its own `requirement.txt` depending if the application is gonna be a web server, a machine learning model or what ever... this simplifies creating cached layer in docker for example. If I need to add some dependencies to the web server, they are added to the web server `requirements.txt` instead of the library one. This is, of course opinionated but my point is that this isn't haskell specific.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation!